# Change a single bar color based on MA direction/color

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to Pine Script and learning to write some simple codes. I've made a HMA script that changes color based on direction. Here's the code:

```
study(title=HMA, overlay=true)    
src = input(close, title=Source)    
len = input(20, title=HMA Length)    
hma1 = hma(src, len)    
hmacolor = change(hma1)>=0 ? color.green : color.red    
plot(hma1, color=hmacolor, title=HMA)    
barcolor(change(hma1)>=0 ? color.green : color.red)
```

I'm able to change the series of bar color using the current barcolor code. But what I'd like instead, is to be able to change just a single bar's color(as a signal) when the direction/color of HMA changes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spot the change of the hmacolor variable as is shown in the example below:

```
//@version=4
study(title='HMA', overlay=true)    
src = input(close, title='Source')    
len = input(20, title='HMA Length')    
hma1 = hma(src, len)    
hmacolor = change(hma1)>=0 ? color.green : color.red    
plot(hma1, color=hmacolor, title='HMA')    

hmaColorFlip = hmacolor != nz(hmacolor[1])

barcolor(hmaColorFlip ? hmacolor : na)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! This is just perfect. Thank you so much (: I'll continue learning about these variables and functions.